# How to know the discriminator value

Tags: hibernate, discriminator

First of all I wanna thank the administrator of this forum and all people who participate in it, that’s my first question that I post,
So let’s take this example of mapping with hibernate,

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PROJ_TYPE")
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public abstract class Project {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("L")
public class LargeProject extends Project {
  private BigDecimal budget;
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class SmallProject extends Project {
}
```

So I have one table with discriminator value, I make a function that return a Project  from the database with Hql and I wanna  know how can I know the discriminator value of this object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: This topic can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584038/java-hibernate-selecting-the-discriminator-column-in-polymorphic-hql-query